# Can't login users in Laravel 4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I try to create a login system in Laravel 4. For this, I use `Auth` build in it. First off, I didn't create a register page just yet, so I created a user inside my DB. For password, I used

> echo Hash::make('password');

It gave me a hash, I pasted in in `pass` field. Now, I want to log the user in. For this, I created a route:

```
Route::post('/users/login/try', array('as' => 'loginTry'), function() {
    $user = array(
        'name' => Input::get('user'),
        'pass' => Hash::make(Input::get('pass'))
    );

    if(Auth::attempt($user,true)) {
        return Redirect::intended('dashboard');
    } else {
        return Redirect::to('/users/login');
    }
});
```

and a view:

```
{{ Form::open(array('route' => 'loginTry')) }}
<p>{{ Form::label('user','Nazwa użytkownika') }} {{ Form::text('user') }}</p>
<p>{{ Form::label('pass','Hasło') }} {{ Form::password('pass') }}</p>
<p>{{ Form::submit('Zaloguj') }}</p>
{{ Form::close() }}
```

When I try to submit the form, I get

```
call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, no array or string given
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Remove Hash::make. Auth::attempt automatically adds it.

Comment: Thanks. Didn't help though.

Comment: Have a look at Named Routes part. (http://four.laravel.com/docs/routing) Your callback has to be inside the array, not the third parameter.

Answer (score 7):

You're giving callback as a third parameter. Move it inside array and it will work.

```
Route::post('/users/login/try', array('as' => 'loginTry', function() {
    //Your callback code here.
}));
```

Comment: Worked! But I can't login, I mean, it acts like the password didn't match. But it should.

Comment: Did you remove Hash::make from 'pass'?

Comment: Yes. It's `'pass' => Input::get('pass')` now.

Comment: Try renaming name and pass to username and password respectively. If it doesn't work, dump "$user" and "Auth::attempt($user,true)". (Use dd() function of Laravel for dumping.) See if something unexpected going on there. Also, after Auth::attempt, dump Auth::check() to see what it returns. Doublecheck your application configuration files to make a valid connection to database. One of those should fix your issue. The code looks valid.

Comment: Changing names didn't work. Database connections are fine, since I can get the data in other files. Dumped $user gives `array(2) { ["username"]=> string(5) "tomek" ["password"]=> string(8) "password" }`, dumped `Auth::check` (and `Auth::attempt`) gives `false`.

Comment: The keys of the credentials array should match the column names. So keep them as `username` and `password`.